# The advantage of while loop over if condition

Tags: bash

I watched a video of Linux from YouTube where a `while` loop is recommended instead of an `if` condition:
[The mind behind Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8NPllzkFhE)

I try to understand it from a novice perspective:

`if` branch code:

```
count=1
if (( count >= 0 )); then
    echo "$count ge 0."
fi
```

and `while` loop code:

```
count=1
while (( count >= 0 )); 
do   
    echo "$count ge 0."
    break
done
```

They produced the same results, but `while` seems more complicated.

What's the advantage of `while` over `if`?

Comment: Could you specify/link the **exact time** in the video, at which the statement is made? The video is > 20 minutes long. I doubt everyone wants to watch the whole video just to give you an answer.

Comment: Specify the time, or better, post the exact quote so the question becomes self-contained.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 But there's a break...?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Technically, but there's an unconditional `break` in the body, so it's limited to one iteration in practice.

Comment: It will be executed once, due to the `break`.

Comment: @chepner, Benjamin, yeah saw that now, sure.

Comment: @schorsch312, so in simple language loop is for doing a task multiple times BUT on other hand if is for doing either this or that. Loop conditions will tell loop till when they have to run, a loop condition can't do either do this or do that. Is major difference of it, so if a loop is running 1 time only(in this case) then you could better use if.

Comment: Just a quick scan through the linked video, but I don't see any mention of shell code *anywhere*, let alone a suggestion that an `if` statement be replaced with a `while` in this manner.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I agree and this is exactly, why I said using the `while` construct is leaving me a bit puzzled about the authors intention, whereas the `if` construct is quite clear (although a simple `    echo "1 ge 0."` would be completely enough in this case.).

Answer (score 2):

In that video Linus doesn't claim while loops are better than ifs, definitely not in the case your simplified example.

It's about eliminating an `if()` (or branch) by using pointers and loops when possible.

The "ugly" code:

```
remove_list_entry(entry)
{
    prev = NULL;
    walk = head;

    while (walk != entry) {
        prev = walk;
        walk = walk->next;
    }

    if (!prev)
        head = entry->next;
    else
        prev->next = entry->next;
}
```

The "clean" code:

```
remove_list_entry(entry)
{
    indirect = &head;

    while ((*indirect) != entry)
        indirect = &(*indirect)->next;

    *indirect = entry->next;
}
```